# Probably a very basic question: can I build and maintain the same website (in Django) from both Windows and macOS?

Tags: django, windows, macos

***Disclaimer:***
First, I apologise if I'm incorrectly applying technical terms here or, worse, completely misunderstanding things. I'll edit if corrected.

***Context:***

Lately I've been building and deploying some basic website ideas to Heroku using the Django framework. I've been doing this on Windows, using venv as my virtual environment "wrapper". I've been building these exclusively from the command line interface.

I also have a MacBook that I'd like to use to access and manage those websites, and in future, larger projects. I would prefer not to install Windows on this MacBook.

To be clear, I know that it's possible to build and deploy a website using Django and Heroku on macOS. I know there are, at the very least, some syntactical differences in how I would approach this from the CLI versus Terminal.

***Desired outcome:***

I would like to set up a website in the fashion indicated above on Windows or macOS, and then access and manipulate it from the other OS.

***Questions:***

Is this possible? (Or if I set it up on Windows must I only use Windows to manage it?)

If I set up a website in this fashion using Django, Heroku, and venv on Windows, how (if at all) might I then access and manipulate that website from macOS? I think what I'm mostly stuck on is that, as far as I can tell, I can't use the same virtual environment on both Windows and macOS (I believe venv is itself Windows-only).

Is it possible to "wrap" my website in both venv (Windows) and virtualenv (macOS)?

Am I correct in thinking the only real (i.e. non-syntactical) difference that I need to account for is the virtual environment itself?

--

Sorry if I have massive gaps in my knowledge. I'm self-taught and have historically been terrible at asking for help. I'm trying to fill the gaps by improving my question-asking.

Finally, I suspect that the fact I'm using Heroku may be irrelevant, but I'm including that information in case I am mistaken.

Comment: Did you attempt to build the website on your Mac? What problems did you face?

Comment: What does the virtual environment on your machine have anything to do with what you deploy on Heroku? The `requirements.txt` file is how Heroku will install packages. You can manage your website from both macOS and Windows, the only problem you can have is in running locally in case you use some package which is OS specific.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for most of the projects, you will be able to develop your Django web site on Windows, MacOS and Linux simultaneously. Your `virtual environment "wrapper"` doesn't really matter, you will use or install and use the one you like or available on your OS.

Then you will learn about Docker.